# Logstash Error: Address already in use

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I have the following config

```
input {
  beats {
    'port' => '5044'
  }
}
output {
  cloudwatch {
    'region'=> 'us-west-2'
  }
}
```

I have only one conf file in `/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/`

```
bash-4.2$ ls /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
logstash.conf
```

And only one Java process from `ps -ef`. Running this in a container

```
bash-4.2$ ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
logstash     1     0  0 17:33 ?        00:00:00 bash -c echo -e $CONFIG > /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf && /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint
logstash     5     1  6 17:33 ?        00:01:00 /bin/java -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.awt.headl
logstash    62     0  0 17:38 ?        00:00:00 bash
logstash    77    62  0 17:47 ?        00:00:00 ps -ef
```

However logstash fails and gives

```
[2017-12-06T07:36:46,505][ERROR][logstash.pipeline ] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Beats port=>9600, id=>"a585f91b9cdadf6400c91b02e2bd3177cf93afd8-1...
Error: event executor terminated
```

Comment: can you enable the fields log.level: debug & config.debug: true in logstash.yml, then rerun the logstash this will provide more debug output and help to narrow down the problem

Comment: @Ram Yes, thanks. Trying that in a few.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is occurred because of creation of a "logstash.conf" backup file in a same folder where current file is located.
Make sure that after any changes in "logstash.conf" file remove the backup file first if it exit in the same directory of a current file or copy that file in another location

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should kill all Logstash running pipelines using:

```
p_id=$(lsof -n -i :5044 | awk '{ print $2}')
p_id=$(echo $p_id | awk '{ print $2}') 
kill -9 $p_id
```

If the problem still exists, stop and then start other services talking with Logstash, e.g., Filebeat.

Answer (score 0):

please try defining different port number(input section) in logstash file and put the same port number in filebeat.yml as well.
***for example use 5085 instead of 5044***

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, but was able to resolve by killing the background process for the same file. As Both are using the same port.

Solution the the above issue are:

1. Either use different port if the port is being used in another pipeline
2. If its the sapipeline, kill the previous process and start anew.